# Getting "OutstandingToken.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am creating a register method using djangorestframework-simplejwt. I created a custom user in auth using `AbstractBaseUser`. I get this error when I make a POST request of a jwt oauth access token from the client to my API at `/google`.

This is the stack trace:

```
Internal Server Error: /google/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/auth/views.py", line 186, in post
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 227, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 426, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 485, in to_internal_value
    validated_value = validate_method(validated_value)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/auth/serializers.py", line 178, in validate_auth_token
    return register_social_user(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/auth/register.py", line 69, in register_social_user
    'tokens': user.tokens()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/auth/models.py", line 78, in tokens
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/tokens.py", line 288, in for_user
    OutstandingToken.objects.create(
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 656, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 543, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/home/pcname/dev-projects/selfey/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 266, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: user@gmail.com>": "OutstandingToken.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

This is my `views.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from .serializers import GoogleSocialAuthSerializer
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, status, views, permissions
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer, SetNewPasswordSerializer, ResetPasswordEmailRequestSerializer, EmailVerificationSerializer, LoginSerializer, LogoutSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from .models import User
from .utils import Util
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.urls import reverse
import jwt
from django.conf import settings
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
from drf_yasg import openapi
from .renderers import UserRenderer
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, force_str, smart_bytes, DjangoUnicodeDecodeError
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode, urlsafe_base64_encode
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.urls import reverse
from .utils import Util
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
import os


class CustomRedirect(HttpResponsePermanentRedirect):

    allowed_schemes = [os.environ.get('APP_SCHEME'), 'http', 'https']


class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    renderer_classes = (UserRenderer,)

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        user_data = serializer.data
        user = User.objects.get(email=user_data['email'])
        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
        relativeLink = reverse('email-verify')
        absurl = 'http://'+current_site+relativeLink+"?token="+str(token)
        email_body = 'Hi '+user.username + \
            ' Use the link below to verify your email \n' + absurl
        data = {'email_body': email_body, 'to_email': user.email,
                'email_subject': 'Verify your email'}

        Util.send_email(data)
        return Response(user_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


class VerifyEmail(views.APIView):
    serializer_class = EmailVerificationSerializer

    token_param_config = openapi.Parameter(
        'token', in_=openapi.IN_QUERY, description='Description', type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)

    @swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[token_param_config])
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
            user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
            if not user.is_verified:
                user.is_verified = True
                user.save()
            return Response({'email': 'Successfully activated'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Activation Expired'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except jwt.exceptions.DecodeError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid token'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class RequestPasswordResetEmail(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ResetPasswordEmailRequestSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        email = request.data.get('email', '')

        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(smart_bytes(user.id))
            token = PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user)
            current_site = get_current_site(
                request=request).domain
            relativeLink = reverse(
                'password-reset-confirm', kwargs={'uidb64': uidb64, 'token': token})

            redirect_url = request.data.get('redirect_url', '')
            absurl = 'http://'+current_site + relativeLink
            email_body = 'Hello, \n Use link below to reset your password  \n' + \
                absurl+"?redirect_url="+redirect_url
            data = {'email_body': email_body, 'to_email': user.email,
                    'email_subject': 'Reset your passsword'}
            Util.send_email(data)
        return Response({'success': 'We have sent you a link to reset your password'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class PasswordTokenCheckAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = SetNewPasswordSerializer

    def get(self, request, uidb64, token):

        redirect_url = request.GET.get('redirect_url')

        try:
            id = smart_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(id=id)

            if not PasswordResetTokenGenerator().check_token(user, token):
                if len(redirect_url) > 3:
                    return CustomRedirect(redirect_url+'?token_valid=False')
                else:
                    return CustomRedirect(os.environ.get('FRONTEND_URL', '')+'?token_valid=False')

            if redirect_url and len(redirect_url) > 3:
                return CustomRedirect(redirect_url+'?token_valid=True&message=Credentials Valid&uidb64='+uidb64+'&token='+token)
            else:
                return CustomRedirect(os.environ.get('FRONTEND_URL', '')+'?token_valid=False')

        except DjangoUnicodeDecodeError as identifier:
            try:
                if not PasswordResetTokenGenerator().check_token(user):
                    return CustomRedirect(redirect_url+'?token_valid=False')
                    
            except UnboundLocalError as e:
                return Response({'error': 'Token is not valid, please request a new one'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)



class SetNewPasswordAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = SetNewPasswordSerializer

    def patch(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response({'success': True, 'message': 'Password reset success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class LogoutAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LogoutSerializer

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)


class GoogleSocialAuthView(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = GoogleSocialAuthSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        """

        POST with "auth_token"

        Send an idtoken as from google to get user information

        """

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = ((serializer.validated_data)['auth_token'])
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`serializers.py`

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    User, AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin, Group, Permission)

from django.db import models
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('Users should have a username')
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users should have a Email')

        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Password should not be none')

        user = self.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user


AUTH_PROVIDERS = {'google': 'google', 'email': 'email'}


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    auth_provider = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=False,
        null=False, default=AUTH_PROVIDERS.get('email'))
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name='groups',
        blank=True,
        help_text=
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ,
        related_name="my_auth_user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        verbose_name='user permissions',
        blank=True,
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
        related_name="my_auth_user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def tokens(self):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token)
        }
```

My custom user model: `models.py`

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin, Group, Permission)

from django.db import models
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('Users should have a username')
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users should have a Email')

        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Password should not be none')

        user = self.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user


AUTH_PROVIDERS = {'google': 'google', 'email': 'email'}


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    auth_provider = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=False,
        null=False, default=AUTH_PROVIDERS.get('email'))
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name='groups',
        blank=True,
        help_text=
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ,
        related_name="my_auth_user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        verbose_name='user permissions',
        blank=True,
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
        related_name="my_auth_user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def tokens(self):
        print('is an instance of User', isinstance(self, User)) # returns True
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token)
        }
```

This is `register.py`

```py
from .email_backend import EmailBackend
from .models import User
import os
import random
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('.env')

backend = EmailBackend()
def generate_username(name):

    username = "".join(name.split(' ')).lower()
    if not User.objects.filter(email=username).exists():
        return username
    else:
        random_username = username + str(random.randint(0, 1000))
        return generate_username(random_username)


def register_social_user(provider, user_id, email, name):
    filtered_user_by_email = User.objects.filter(email=email)

    if filtered_user_by_email.exists():

        if provider == filtered_user_by_email[0].auth_provider:

            print('email', backend.authenticate(email=email))
            registered_user = backend.authenticate(email=email, password=os.getenv('SOCIAL_SECRET'))

            print('user is already registered', registered_user)

            if registered_user is not None:
                return {
                    'username': registered_user.username,
                    'email': registered_user.email,
                    'tokens': registered_user.tokens()}
            else:
                user = {
                    'username': generate_username(name), 'email': email}
                user = User.objects.create_user(**user)
                user.is_verified = True
                user.auth_provider = provider
                user.save()

                new_user = backend.authenticate(email=email)
                return {
                    'email': new_user.email,
                    'username': new_user.username,
                    'tokens': new_user.tokens()
                }


        else:
            raise AuthenticationFailed(
                detail='Please continue your login using ' + filtered_user_by_email[0].auth_provider)

    else:
        user = {
            'username': generate_username(name), 'email': email,
            'password': os.getenv('SOCIAL_SECRET')}
        user = User.objects.create_user(**user)
        user.is_verified = True
        user.auth_provider = provider
        user.save()

        return {
            'email': user.email,
            'username': user.username,
            'tokens': user.tokens()
        }
```

Custom authentication backend, `email_backend.py`:

```py
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request=None, username=None, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        print("email backend", User.objects.get(email=email).check_password(password))
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user

        return None
```

`requirements.txt`

```
Django
djangorestframework
django-rest-auth
django-tailwind
django-tailwind[reload]
django-cors-headers
djangorestframework-simplejwt
drf-yasg
google-api-core
google-api-python-client
google-auth
google-auth-httplib2
googleapis-common-protos
gunicorn
Pillow
python-dotenv
```

`urls.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from posts.views import PostViewSet, CommentViewSet
from users.views import UserViewSet
from auth.views import GoogleSocialAuthView

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'posts', PostViewSet)
router.register(r'comments', CommentViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('google/', GoogleSocialAuthView.as_view()),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('auth/', include('auth.urls')),
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static (settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Could you include your import statements at the top of the code blocks, and maybe your `requirements.txt` file so that we can easily duplicate your environment? It would also be helpful to know what you are doing when the error is thrown, along with a full stacktrace of the error.